# Why is my JPanel or JFrame not appearing?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I am making a game. There are 3 different files in the project, there is a file called Dude, Frame and Board. So can anyone help me? The code:
The code for Board:
package Ourgame;

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
Dude p;
Image img;
Timer time;

    public Board() {
    p = new Dude();
    addKeyListener(new AL());
    setFocusable(true);
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("/Users/appleuser/Desktop");
    img = i.getImage();
    time = new Timer(5, this);
    time.start();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        p.move();
    repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.drawImage(p.getImage(), p.getX(), p.getY(), null);
    }

    private class AL extends KeyAdapter {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    p.keyReleased(e);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    p.keyPressed(e);
    }
    }
}
```

The code for Dude:

```
    package Ourgame;

    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Dude {
        int x, dx, y;
        Image still;

    public Dude() {
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("/Users/appleuser/Desktop/the man.bmp");
        still = i.getImage();
        x = 10;
        y = 172;
    }

    public void move() {
        x = x + dx;

    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return still;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
        dx = -1;

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        dx = 1;

    }

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
    dx = 0;

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    dx = 0;

}



}
```

The code for Frame:

```
package Ourgame;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("2D game");
    frame.add(new Board());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1200, 365);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to load your desktop as an image?

Comment: This terminal semicolon will mess you up: `if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);`. Get rid of this and similar semicolons throughout your code. Always put **all** code blocks in curly braces, even single line blocks.

Comment: Also, debug your image paths. You're likely better off getting them as resources and not as files. Also use a debugger to identify where your problem is, and post a more detailed description of the problems your program is encountering.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is right, for your if statement put curly brackets after them. You show two instances of a semicolon followed after the closing brace for your if statements. This *might* cause problems.

Comment: @Obicere I'm not, there is a pic on my desktop I'm trying to load.

Comment: @user3287305 that may be the case, but it says you are trying to load the desktop as one in the `Board()` constructor.

Comment: you are certainly not loading an image with the code that @Obicere is pointing out to you.

Comment: You say that your JFrame and your JPanel are "not appearing"? So nothing is showing up? Again, please clarify your problem for us.

Comment: *Update* I changed the image path to the correct path, the JFrame is still not apearing although the console comes and says: run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds). What should I do??

Comment: Code works fine. Check your Image path.

Comment: @Jugadu I just put the right image path but it's still not appearing.

Comment: So there must be some other problem. Are you tried a complete path for `Image` like: `C:/FolderName/Image.bmp`,if not then try it. In my case the Images are overlapping.

Comment: @Jugadu I'm on a mac, the image paths are different

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to call JFrame.pack(). It's possible the layout manager hasn't set the bounds of your Board. Try:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new Board());
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

If this doesn't work then I suggest you follow the other advice on here: use a Debugger and/or check your image paths. "/Users/appleuser/Desktop" is definitely not an image.

Comment: *update* I did type in the right image path, but still, my JPanel or my JFrame would not apear. I did setVisible(true); but i is still not visible.

Comment: That's not what I said. `setVisible()` was already there. I said you *might* need to add `pack()`.

Comment: I copied and pasted that but nothing would happen. I'm freaking out! lol!

Comment: Try changing your paint method to just fill the component with a colour, e.g. using g2.setColor(Color.BLACK) and g2.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight()), to see whether your panel is sized properly. If the colour appears then your images are the problem.

Comment: I did, but nothing would happen. The JFrame is not popping up.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking your Swing code on the EDT:

```
package Ourgame;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("2D game");
        frame.add(new Board());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1200, 365);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I just did, but nothing will happen.

Comment: I suggest you look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html and get the FrameDemo.java working then work from there.